# Knockout-validation group error checking

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a knockout form that is comprised of 2 parts. When the first part is being filled out the second part is hidden. Upon completing the first part and clicking "Continue" the first part is then hidden and the second part is shown. I want to be able to validate the first set of inputs, and if there are no errors then continue to the next part.

I found [this](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Validating-Only-Specific-Observables) on the official github page which I is what I'm attempting to do.

When I do this no errors are detected. It continues to the second part

```
function ReserveViewModel(){

    self.firstName = ko.observable("").extend({ required: true });

    self.continue = function(){
        var errors = ko.validation.group([ReserveViewModel.firstName]);
        if (errors.length == 0) {
            //display  second div
        }
        else{
             self.errors.showAllMessages();
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I do this it works but tries to validate everything. Since the second set of inputs are empty it just hangs there.

```
self.continue = function(){
    self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);
    if (self.errors().length == 0) {

    }
    else{
        self.errors.showAllMessages();
    }
}
```

Comment: So if you do it the first way it works like you intend for it to - why would you use the second way?  Why not just use two separate view models and have two groups of validation rules?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I either get no validation, or total validation with what I have shown. I suppose I could create two separate view models, I never thought about it that way. Regardless, I'm still confused as to why I can't get my example to work when it's shown that way in the documentation.

Comment: When I read your question it was not yet clear to me why the first way wasn't working.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a few fundamental reasons that your code isn't working.  In the first example, you are already within the context of your view model so you don't need to use ReserveViewModel.firstName, and in the second you are saying to check everything within 'self' which is to say check everything within me for validation.  There are two ways easy ways to skin this cat (as I see it, having only briefly worked with KO.Validation) -

Deep validation -

```
function Person(firstname, lastname) {
    var firstName = ko.observable(firstname).extend({ required: true });
    var lastName = ko.observable(lastname).extend({ required: true });
}

function ReserveViewModel(){

    self.person = ko.observable(new Person('John', 'Jingleheimer'));

    self.continue = function(){
        var errors = ko.validation.group(self.person, { deep: true });
        if (errors.length == 0) {
            //display  second div
        }
        else{
             self.errors.showAllMessages();
        }
    }
}
```

This will validate all of the properties of person and it's 'child' properties to ensure validation.

The next example would be to simply create an array of objects to check against -

```
function myViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
    self.lastName = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
    self.someOtherProperty = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });

    var firstStepValidation = [
        self.firstName,
        self.lastName
    ];

    var secondStepValidation = [
        self.someOtherProperty
    ];

    self.continue = function(){
        var errors = ko.validation.group(firstStepValidation);
        if (errors.length == 0) {
            //display  second div
        }
        else{
             self.errors.showAllMessages();
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow you to 'chunk' your observables into arrays to test against.  This would probably be easier than trying to create separate view models.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the second "chunk" example is exactly what I was looking for.